# Pass PHP variable into html file

Tags: php, variables, indexing

I'm trying to pass a variable in PHP in the same page. The form is:

```
<form name="form1" method="POST" action="index.php">
<input type="text" name="F1" value="" size="35">
</br>
<input type="submit" name="B1" value="Go!">
</form>
```

and the PHP script is:

```
<?php

        if(isset($_POST['B1']))
        {
         $u=$_POST['F1'];

            $document=new domDocument('1.0', 'WINDOWS-1251');
            $document->loadHTML
            ('<html>
                <head>
                    <title></title>


                </head>
            <body>


                echo  $u;


            </body>
            </html>');

            $document->formatOutput=true;
            $document->encoding='WINDOWS-1251';
            $document->saveHTMLFile("output.php");

        }
        ?>
```

The script is meant to create an "output.php" file that prints the content of the text area decleared in the form, but it not works, what can I do?

Thanks!

Comment: What doesn't work? What error do you get? What have you done to debug it?

Comment: What do you mean `doesn't work`? Does the file not get created? Is the outputted text incorrect?

Comment: You're using single-quotes inside `$document->loadHTML()`, so it wouldn't use the actual variable value. You need to wrap it in double-quotes instead. See [documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php) for why.

Comment: Try using double quotes (") instead of the single ones (') in the loadHTML method (I guess the echo before $u is not necessary).

Answer (score 2):

change this:

```
$document->loadHTML
    ('<html>
        <head>
            <title></title>
        </head>
        <body>
            echo  $u;
        </body>
    </html>');
```

to

```
$document->loadHTML
    ('<html>
        <head>
            <title></title>
        </head>
        <body>
            '.$u.'
        </body>
    </html>');
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also use like

```
 $document->loadHTML
  ("<html>
    <head>
        <title></title>
    </head>
    <body>
      $u
    </body>
  </html>");
```